# Could somebody please explain?

Tags: java, for-loop

I have three Java codes that involve printing different sets of numbers using for loops. They work, however, I have literally no clue why they work. Could somebody please help?

The first one (below, Main1) prints the numbers from 23 to 89 with 10 numbers on each line and one space in between each number.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.Math; 

class Main1 {
    public static void main(String[] args)
     {
  for (int i = 23; i < 90; ++i) {
            System.out.print(i);
            char c;
            if (i % 10 == 2) { c = '\n'; } 
            else { c = ' '; }
            System.out.print(c);
    }
  }
}
```

The second one (below, Main2) has the user input an integer between zero and a hundred with twenty numbers per line. If the number is not between zero and a hundred, it prints "error."

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.Math; 

class Main2 {
    public static void main(String[] args)
     {
 Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("Enter a number between 0 and 100:");
  int x = scan.nextInt();
  if(x > 0 || x < 100){
  for(int a = x; a < 101; a++){
    System.out.println(a);
  }
 }
 if(x < 0 || x > 100)System.out.println("error");
}

}
```

And the third one (again below, class Main3) prints only the even numbers from one to fifty with one on each line.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.Math; 

class Main3 {
    public static void main(String[] args)
     {
    for(int i = 2; i <= 50; i++)
    {
    if (i%2 == 0)
      System.out.println(i);

    }
    }
}
```

All of these work as supposed to, I'm just not sure *how*. Thank you!

Comment: You've mixed up your examples. They are all very basic loops though, you should spend more time reading books and following tutorials if you "have no clue" what the code is doing. (Formatting your code properly would also help with understanding. Most IDEs/code editors have features for that; learn to use them.)

Comment: I alway found it helpful when learning a programming language is to become familiar with the debugger stepping through each line of code and then looking at the variables and the output to see what happened. It helped me understand both the code and how to use a debugger.  A good Java tutorial will also help you. There are several really good ones a search engine away.

Comment: what do you not understand regarding the *how*?

Comment: Reminder that this site is a Q&A site not a tutorial site. For a question like this I recommend reading through a Java tutorial, there are many good ones out there, like [this one](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/). Additionally, please read through the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide. Thank you for reading through the tour page and welcome to StackOverflow!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first Java code,

this prints the numbers 23 to 33

```
   for (int i = 23; i < 90; ++i) {
                System.out.print(i);
```

until you have the condition

```
if (i % 10 == 2) { 
c = '\n'; 
} 
else { 
c = ' ';
 }
System.out.print(c);
```

if the i has divisible by 10 and has a remainder of two then the value of c will be \n 
else
c will have the value if " ".

In your second code,

you will enter a number between 1 and 100, then the code

```
if(x > 0 || x < 100)
```

will check if the number is between 0 and 100, then if the condition is true it will have a loop

```
for(int a = x; a < 101; a++){
    System.out.println(a);
  }
```

this loop will print starting to the number you entered until 100.
And then this code,

```
if(x < 0 || x > 100)System.out.println("error");
```

will check if you have entered a number that is 0 and below, and 100 and up;

your third code, this for loop

```
for(int i = 2; i <= 50; i++)
```

will loop from 2 to 50

but you have the condition of

```
if (i%2 == 0)
      System.out.println(i);

    }
```

this means that of the i is divisible by two, it will print the i.

Hope you understood all my explanation.